# ZF2 + Doctrine2 Attach Entity Listener

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm developing an app based on top of Zend Framework 2 and Doctrine 2.

I discovered 2 days ago that doctrine now allows to bind Entity Listeners to manage lifecycle callbacks (as prePersist, preUpdate, postLoad...)

I have an Entity declared in a first module (and configured for Doctrine with Annotations).

In another module i wrote an EntityListener that i want to bind programmatically to my Entity.

I definitely can't use the annotation "@EntityListeners({"MyListenerClass"})" on my Entity as my first module needs to stay independant of the second one (where the listener is declared)

I actually tried to bind it by doing the following in my listener's module bootstrap :

```
$em = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
/* @var $em \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
$entityListener = new EntityListener();
$entityListener->setServiceManager($e->getApplication()->getServiceManager());
$em->getConfiguration()->getEntityListenerResolver()->register($entityListener);
```

With some output logging i just saw that this way does not work (i never told that my entity had an Entity Listener) and maybe this code is just uncomplete

Does someone now how to bind it without using configuration (Annot, XML or YAML) ?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: I won't venture an Answer because I'm not sure, but I _think_ the answer is:  you have to have the annotation (or config). In my several experiments I have tried the manual method and/or the annotation and have found that without the annotation, the manual method alone just doesn't work.

If you're really determined, you can use the ZF event manager instead of Doctrine's and `trigger()` in your entity.